# Flash: disabling certain security sandbox problems

Tags: apache-flex, sandbox, filereference

Is there a way to disable certain unnecessary security sandbox protections, on all platforms? I'm running Flex 3.5 and our customers are going to be very irritated if when I download a series of files using FileReference.download() they are going to have to keep clicking on all these dialogues for each file (you see, FileReference.download() can only be called as a result of user interaction, so the best workaround I could find is having an Alert.show() precede each file download, which means users would have to acknowledge both the Alert.show() plus the file dialogue that FileReference.download() throws up.) Since we setup the systems, I'm sure our customers will allow us to disable some of the sandbox features, if it's at all possible.

Comment: From what I remember about the FileReference piece, the security is way, way deep down in the architecture.  The best thing I can say is that if you know they are going to download more than one file, zip them up on the backend and deliver it in one download.

Comment: I wish Flash made it possible for the client to change those settings. Now our customers are going to be annoyed w/us because Flash is protecting them from our solutions.

There are a couple of reasons that won't work: one is it changes the behaviour which will force the user to then unzip a file manually. Another is that these are huge files, so getting them all in one download is not acceptable.

What the highers up tell me *is* acceptable is having all the downloads concurrent, so that the user doesn't have to wait until one file finishes to start another. I foresee big problems but...

Comment: If you can do concurrent downloads, I would suggest using "ExternalInterface" and doing so in JS if at all possible.  In that event, you would window.redirect the user to a destination and you would start the download there using session data.

Comment: I looked into a JS solution. In the end I turned up nothing. It seems I can't rely on getting the file dialogue to appear. Also, I've discovered another problem w/the concurrency: most browsers(?) limit the number of current sockets you can have open w/any one server.

Comment: @PenguinList Yes, they do limit the number of open sockets.  But that's mostly older browsers (limit of 2), now they allow up to 6 if I remember correctly.  If you have more than 6 going, you might want to think up another solution.  I've never had a problem getting a download dialog to start.